# @Html.HiddenFor to bind html table with viewModel

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, model-binding

I've a list in `viewModel` and trying to bind that list with html table. First I try `foreach loop`, It generates table but on form submit it always send null list to controller.

Then on searching, i got to know that I've to use `for loop` for binding.. Now I tried for loop like this

```
 @for(int i =0; i< Model.lstTrainingCourses.Count; i++)
       {
           <tr>
               <td hidden>@Html.HiddenFor(tc => Model.lstTrainingCourses[i].UserTrainingCoursesDetailId)</td>
               <td hidden>@Html.DisplayFor(tc => Model.lstTrainingCourses[i].TrainingCourses)</td>
           </tr>
       }
```

But it only send first column value, and pass 2nd column as null in list on form submit.

I've also tried `@Html.TextBoxFor` but it gives a textbox in table, that I dont need.

then I changed 2nd column like this;

```
         <td hidden>@Html.HiddenFor(tc => Model.lstTrainingCourses[i].TrainingCourses)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(tc => Model.lstTrainingCourses[i].TrainingCourses)</td>
```

It does exactly what i want. But I've to repeat same columns again for binding. So I need suggestions either this approach is good or not? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**Update : read-only with @Html.TextBoxFor**

I even tried this one (only on first column)

```
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(tc => Model.lstTrainingCourses[i].TrainingCourses, new { @readonly = true })</td>
```

and it results to this one

[image: textboxFor]

it makes textbox readonly But shows textbox in column and does not even bind its value properly. I want column like 2nd one (Start Date).

Comment: A form only posts back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls, and `DisplayFor()` does not create a form control. You can always use a read-only textbox rather than both `HiddenFor()` and `DisplayFor()`

Comment: It will bind correctly (and its `new { readonly="readonly" }`). And you can always add a class name and style it to look however you want

Comment: what is the signature of the controller method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it does not accept `new { readonly="readonly" }`

Comment: Sorry, left of the leading `@` - `new { @readonly="readonly" }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke working now. thank you.

Comment: @DaveBecker here it is

` [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProfile(EditUserViewModel eUser)`